# ¿Qué significa el apartado etiquetas dentro de la pestaña "actividad" de mi perfil?

Tags: soporte, reputación, perfil

Reviso mi perfil y me encuentro [con una zona](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/75901/%CE%B1%CE%BB%CF%81%CE%B8%CE%B1?tab=topactivity) donde aparecen etiquetas de distintas tecnologías donde he participado respondiendo, en algunas más en otras menos. Sin embargo, aunque al colocar el cursor encima del número de la izquierda aparece un texto, no me termina de quedar claro: ¿este puntaje es el que llevo acumulado por etiqueta de cada tecnología mencionada?

Dejo una imagen que hace referencia a lo que menciono:

> [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Analicemos el primer caso por ejemplo, [php](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php).

Si te pones encima del 341, aparece el siguiente texto:

> Formuló 8 preguntas que no son wiki con una puntuación total de 13. Proporcionó 219 respuestas que no son de wiki con una puntuación total de 341.

Como vemos, el segundo número que aparece (227) es el número total de publicaciones en esa etiqueta (8 preguntas + 219 respuestas).

En cuanto a las puntuaciones totales, tanto en preguntas como en respuestas, que supongo que es realmente tu duda, se calcula sumando los votos positivos en tus publicaciones y restando los negativos. Es decir, si tu realizas una pregunta con la etiqueta [php](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php), y recibes 10 votos positivos y 8 negativos, la puntuación total en esa etiqueta aumentaría en 2 puntos.